# Modifying the search engines in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I'd like to change the default google search from Chrome to

```
http://www.google.ro/search?q=${search}&esrch=BetaShortcuts
```

the reason being the the localised version of the search engine does not apply the keyboard shortcuts experiment.

How can I change the search engine settings in Chrome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just go to the preferences menu -> Basics, and next to default search there is a manage button.

In the resulting popup add a search engine, come up with a name, keyword, and for the URL just use `http://www.google.ro/search?q=%s&esrch=BetaShortcuts`. This should work.

I'm on OS X so the steps may be a little different but it should be the same on linux and windows.

When you're done with that click on the new option you've created and press "Make Default".